# pandas dataframe - filtering gives unexpected error 'unorderable types'

Tags: python, pandas

The following snippet of Python gives me an error:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['UBS','UBS','ABB','UBS'], 'B': ['L', 'L', 'L', 'D']})
cols = ['A', 'A', 'B']
df = df[cols]
df = df[df['A'].isin(['UBS']) & (df['B'] != 'D')]
```

The error that I get is `unorderable types: str() < int()`. I would understand if it was complaining about the duplicate column, but why is it trying (and failing) to compare integers and strings?

If I replace the last line by `df = df[df['A'].isin(['UBS'])]` I do get the expected error message, `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

Admittedly this example is contrived (it's a boiled-down example of real code), and the code works fine if I exchange the last two rows, but I would still like to understand the error.

Comment: What version of python and pandas do you have?

Comment: I can reproduce this using pandas `0.15.2` numpy `1.9.2rc1`

Comment: What python version?

Comment: I think this is a python 3 specific error, is that possible? (I don't get it with 2.7.9, but can reproduce it with 3.3.5). This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes my python version is 3.4

Comment: I am using Python 3.3, numpy 1.9.1, Pandas 0.14.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception occurs when Pandas computes

```
df['A'].isin(['UBS']) & (df['B'] != 'D')
```

The first expression is a boolean-valued Dataframe, the second is a boolean-valued Series. The DataFrame's primary axis, the column axis, has index

```
Index(['A', 'A'], dtype='object')
```

while the Series' primary axis has index

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Pandas tries to align these two Indexes, and as part of that process the values in the indexes are compared. In Python2 strings and ints are comparable, in Python3 the comparison raises an exception.

---

If you run the code under Python3, the traceback error message ends with

```
  File "/home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2_226_ge1aaf8c-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 2005, in _join_monotonic
    join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)
  File "pandas/src/generated.pyx", line 8558, in pandas.algos.outer_join_indexer_object (pandas/algos.c:157918)
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Now if you insert

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

into the code before the exception is raised, and then re-run the script,
you can set a break point on the last line in Python where the exception occurs:

```
(Pdb) b /home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2_226_ge1aaf8c-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py:2005
Breakpoint 1 at /home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2_226_ge1aaf8c-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py:2005
(Pdb) cont
> /home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas-0.15.2_226_ge1aaf8c-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py(2005)_join_monotonic()
-> join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)
```

And now you can inspect the value of the offending variables:

```
(Pdb) p sv
array(['A', 'A'], dtype=object)
(Pdb) p ov
array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
(Pdb) q
```

This shows that `sv` contains strings and `ov` contains ints. In Python2, `str`s and `int`s are comparable -- [In CPython any `str` is greater than any `int`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) -- so no exception is raised in `pandas/src/generated.pyx` when `lval` is compared with `rval`:

```
        elif lval < rval:
            count += 1
            i += 1
```

But [in Python3, `str`s and `int`s are no longer comparable](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). So an exception is raised earlier in Python3 than in Python2. In Python2 the error comes later and raises

```
cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

You get the same error with `df = df[df['A'].isin(['UBS'])]`, rather than the `unorderable types` error, since there is no `&` here.

Comment: Nice! Maybe add the explanation of the underlying (or above-lying) reason why this error is raised: when comparing a series with datafame, the series index is matched with the dataframe columns (and not index), so for this reason, it will error?

Comment: @joris: Right. I think the error can occur (in Python3) whenever Indexes with incomparable values are joined or aligned.